# How can a single java thread execute more than one native method at a time?

Tags: android, multithreading, garbage-collection, java-native-interface, swig

I am trying to track down a problem in my Android application. This problem causes a crash during garbage collection in the native layer of the code. I'll explain myself.

My application consists merely in java source controlling GUI elements and such and a native library that manages rendering and other performance-critical parts of the application. It features a GLSurfaceView for rendering.

The java layer needs to be able to access and instantiate native objects, so these are exposed to Java through Swig. What Swig does is that in each wrapper class (in Java) it generates a finalize method that will call the native delete operator.

Consider the following pseudo-code:

In C++:

```
class MyClass {

    public:

        MyClass () {}

        ~MyClass ()
        {
            print("deleting MyClass instance");
            print("doing 1");
            do1();
            print("doing 2");
            do2();
            print("doing 3");
            do3();
            print("instance deleted");
        }
};
```

This is pseudo code meaning that for example "print" stands for print in android logcat I was just Keeping It Simply Stupid ;) .

What puzzles me is that when the garbage collector runs, and calls  the destructors in some cases I can find the output interleaved between multiple destructors (as if they were being deleted concurrently). In this example case it could be :

```
deleting MyClass instance
doing 1
deleting MyClass instance
doing2
doing1
doing2
deleting MyClass instance
doing3
doing3
instance deleted
doing1
doing2
instance deleted
doing3
instance deleted
```

While at the same time logcat clearly states that these messages originate from the same thread (the finalizer thread).

Hence my question: "How can a single thread be executing multiple native calls at the same time ?"

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052064/jvm-garbage-collection

Comment: @Samhain that's not applicable here, as this occurs in the Dalvik VM, not the JVM

Comment: Thanks @TassosBassoukos, I think too that the linked question does not explain the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Does the native destructor call back into the VM?